# In what cases do 平板 verbs change their pitch?

Tags: pitch-accent

I recently realized that 平板 verbs become 尾高 when there is a の after them. For example:

戦うの→たたかうの{LHHHL}

寝るの→ねるの{LHL}

That really does happen right? Or am I mishearing? What are other situations where 平板 verbs change their pitch like that?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, that does happen. It happens in a couple other places, certainly including ん but also:

- から
- けど
- が (as a conjunction and (verb)がいい etc)
- many sentences ending particles (ぞ (optional)、わ (male version only)、よ (optional)、さ、 な (negative imperative only)、っけ、 etc.)
- に違いない
- も (when it directly follows a verb — you can imagine it as an invisible の almost)
- か (for compartmentalizer & for sentence-ending question marker in the rhetorical usage)
- し
- と (quotative particle)、って、なんて
- と (conjunction particle, optional)

and probably more.

Comment: Is と (conjunction particle, optional) the same as conditional ''if''? I think I hear やめちゃうと as やめちゃうと{LHHHLL} in https://voca.ro/14KSa4RrEFtC. I wonder if this is just the normal traits of ちゃう but I'm not sure there. It seems like she is at least emphasizing because in https://vocaroo.com/11VHJDm5otaC it sounds like やめちゃう{LHHHH} with no と after it?

Comment: Yes, that's the と I was referring to in that bullet. It's marked as optional because both やめちゃうと￣ and やめちゃ＼うと are fine. The latter doesn't feel like emphasis to me, just alternative way to say it.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "compartmentalizer"? Are you referring to the type of か as in "○○になる**か**わからない"?