# Can the か particle change the pitch accent of verbs?

Tags: verbs, pitch-accent

Consider the Heiban verb やる. According to [a video on Japanese verb pitch accent rules](https://youtu.be/clOfEb5Jjp0?t=466), Heiban verbs with no downsteps remain Heiban when conjugated to their negative form. [Prosody](https://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/ojad/eng/phrasing/index) confirms this rule with やらない:

> [image]

But if I add a か particle after it, it completely changes the pitch pattern detected:

> [image]

Is this a mistake with Prosody, or can clause ending particles like か (and others like ね, な, の, etc) affect the pitch of the verbs before them?

Comment: I have noticed that too but I wonder if that's intonation as opposed to pitch

Comment: I think it's the same with よ, and the accent falls on な instead of い because the accent doesn't like to be at the end of a diphthong. I'm not sure though.

Comment: Kaskade: How would the accent fall on the end of the diphthong if it were heiban (e.g. yaRANAIYO)?

Comment: @Kaskade - ない doesn’t form a diphthong but is pronounced in two moras, and the accent does fall on い.

Comment: Related: [In what cases do 平板 verbs change their pitch?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/82408/3097)